# SharePoint add item to custom list results in "Invalid URL value. A URL field contains invalid data. Please check the value and try again"

Tags: c#, sharepoint, powershell

### Setup

I am programmatically adding elements to a custom list with custom columns from C# code:

```
// Get the list
var context = SPContext.Current;
var web = context.Site.RootWeb;
web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;    
var favoritesList = web.Lists["Favoritter"];

// Check if new item already exists
var query = new SPQuery
{
    Query = string.Format(
            "<Where>" +
            "<And>" +
            "<Eq><FieldRef Name='Brugernavn'/><Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value></Eq>" +
            "<And>" +
            "<Eq><FieldRef Name='Fagomr_x00e5_de'/><Value Type='Text'>{1}</Value></Eq>" +
            "<Eq><FieldRef Name='N_x00f8_gletalsnummer'/><Value Type='Text'>{2}</Value></Eq>" +
            "</And>" +
            "</And>" +
            "</Where>", GetUserName(false), omraade, noegletalsId)
};

var items = favoritesList.GetItems(query);

if (items.Count > 0)
    return false;

// Otherwise add the new item
var favorite = favoritesList.Items.Add();
favorite["Brugernavn"] = GetUserName(false);
favorite["Fagomr_x00e5_de"] = omraade;
favorite["N_x00f8_gletalsnummer"] = noegletalsId;
favorite.Update(); // <--- THIS LINE THROWS EXCEPTION

web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;

return true;
```

### The problem

When I perform the `Update()` command on the new item the following exception is thrown:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException:
Invalid URL value. A URL field contains invalid data. Please check the value and try again
```

### Additional information

The three custom columns I have made are all of type `SPFieldText` and thus have *nothing* to do with URLs.

I have also hidden the default Title field using PowerShell:

```
$titleField = $favoritesList.Fields.GetField("Title")
$titleField.LinkToItem = $false
$titleField.Required = $false
$titleField.Hidden = $true
$titleField.Update()
```

The XML schema for list can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dg439upzym6cu09/Schema.xml).

Comment: Can you post you list structure? Maybe you have an mandatory URL field which isn't filled.

Comment: Yes, if you can tell me how to find it :)

Comment: In your site, navigate to your list definition and locate URL fields marked as mandatory.

Comment: I have added a link to the schema above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you checked whether your list variable (favoritesList) contains reference to the list that you are trying to access.

It would be better to use SPWeb.Lists.TrygetList (http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.splistcollection.trygetlist.aspx) instead of using web.Lists[]. TrygetList will return null if the specific list could not be found, so that you can make sure favoritesList variable has reference to the list library.

Also you can use SPWeb.getlist (http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.getlist.aspx) and check for execption.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It turned out that I was using a slightly different URL when getting the `SPWeb` containing the list, thus resulting in not getting the right list.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't use `SPList.Items` collection due to performance reasons. Use `SPList.AddItem` method instead.

Second, the problem is in arguments of `Add` method. First argument should be the server-relative URL of the folder where the list item should be created. You need to get folder from list and then get it's url.
Or maybe you can use just `favoritesList.AddItem()`

Comment: About the parameters for the `Add()` method: I pasted in the wrong piece of code. I actually used the overload, that takes zero parameters. I have updated it above now.